# How to get the text of an element if that is only present in devtool using robot framework?

Tags: python, xpath, robotframework

I want to get the text **"5831"** from this element which is only present in devtool, I already tried using this following code but the can't still get text.

```
${td_inputverificationpin}    get text  ${textPin}
page should contain    ${td_inputverificationpin}
log to console    verifcation code: ${td_inputverificationpin}
input text    ${inputPin}    ${td_inputverificationpin}
```

This is my code
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nWKQ.jpg)

My locator(xpath)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5HEQ.jpg)

The result. It is supposed to be

verification code: 5831
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdWOD.jpg)

Comment: How does your script end? What does it log into console? How does your selector in `${textPin}` look like?

Comment: I already got the answer for this. Thank You 